# Problems with asyncio in 3.4.2 - it just terminates for some reason

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, python-asyncio

A newbie at python and spending many hours reading docs and other code I cannot seem to get the new [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module in Python 3.
It keeps on terminating without a stack trace to give me a clue and should run forever but does not.

The fundamental process concept I am trying to emulate is the following:

*read from port:*
open port -> read data (variable length) -> place on queue1

*then process data:*
get data from queue1 -> condition applies -> outcome put on queue2

*then write to port:*
get data from queue2 and write to port

loop around from top forever

Note: The data on the in port is sporadic, variable length and several blocks may arrive out of 'sequence' thus I use `asyncio`. I understand `asyncio` will allow the case of a block arrives, then another prior to my app responding - i.e. the call `get_io_from_port()` facilitates multiple executions of the co-routine. This is why I have use the queues to ensure non-blocking of the `process_queue()`

My toy example code so far:

```
import queue
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def process_queue(q1, q2):
    tmp = q1.Get()
    if tmp == 'ABCDEF':
        q2.put('12345')
    elif tmp == 'GHIJKL':
        q2.put =('67890')
    else:
        print('There is a data error')

@asyncio.coroutine
def put_io_to_port(writer, q2):

    if not q2.empty():
        try:
                writer.write(q2.get())

        except IOError as e:
            print('OUT Port issue: ', e)

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_io_from_port(reader, q1):

    try:
        data_i = yield from reader.read(1200)
        q1.put(data_i)

    except IOError as e:
        print('IN Port issue: ', e)

def main():

    q1 = queue()
    q2 = queue()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()     # main loop declaration
    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('192.168.1.103', 5555)
                # high-level call open streams - read and write

    print('Start')
    tasks = [
        asyncio.async(get_io_from_port(reader,q1)),
        asyncio.async(process_queue(q1, q2)),
        asyncio.async(put_io_to_port(writer, q2)),]  # do these tasks - in this order

    loop.run_forever(tasks)     # loop through on main loop forever
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, as an aside - how does one debug this code - ie tracing? What techniques could be suggested? I am using Eclipse and PyDev but to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

You've made several mistakes here. First, you're treating `main` like its a normal function, but you've placed a `yield from` call in there, which will automatically convert it into a generator. That means when you do

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`main` is not actually executed; the call to `main()` just creates a generator object that's immediately thrown away (because you're not assigning it to a variable). This is why you're having a hard time debugging - none of the code inside `main` is even executing. You should convert `main` to be a coroutine and call it using `loop.run_until_complete` instead.

Next, you're trying to use the `queue` module, which is not designed for use in a single-threaded asynchronous program. As soon as you call `queue.get()`, it's going to block your main thread, which means your `asyncio` event loop will be blocked, which means your whole program will be deadlocked. You should use the coroutine-safe [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue) instead.

You also have a race condition in `put_io_to_port`. You're only trying to consume from `q2` if it isn't empty, but its possible that `put_io_to_port` could execute before `process_queue` has a chance to run and populate the `queue`. It looks like you would be fine if you just removed the `if not q2.empty()` check from `put_io_to_port` altogether.

Finally, you're adding your coroutines to the event loop using `asyncio.async`, which is fine. But you have a comment that says `# do these tasks, in this order`, but that's not how the program will behave with `asyncio.async`. It just adds all the coroutines to the event loop, and they'll all run in parallel. If you really want them to run sequentially, you should just do:

```
yield from get_io_from_port(reader,q1)
yield from process_queue(q1, q2)
yield from put_io_to_port(writer, q2)
```

But that's really not necessary here. You can run all of them at the same time and get the correct behavior; if one coroutine executes ahead of the other, it will just wait until the coroutine it depends on passes it the data it needs, and then resume execution.

You also have a few typos in there (`q1.Get()`, `q2.put =(...)`, etc).

So, put all those fixes together and you get this:

```
import queue
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def process_queue(q1, q2):
    while True:
        tmp = yield from q1.get()
        if tmp == 'ABCDEF':
            yield from q2.put('12345')
        elif tmp == 'GHIJKL':
            yield from q2.put('67890')
        else:
            print('There is a data error')

@asyncio.coroutine
def put_io_to_port(writer, q2):
    while True:
        try:
            data = yield from q2.get()
            writer.write(data)
        except IOError as e:
            print('OUT Port issue: ', e)

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_io_from_port(reader, q1):
    while True:
        try:
            data_i = yield from reader.read(1200)
            yield from q1.put(data_i)
        except IOError as e:
            print('IN Port issue: ', e)

@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    q1 = asyncio.Queue()
    q2 = asyncio.Queue()

    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('192.168.1.103', 5555)
                # high-level call open streams - read and write

    print('Start')
    tasks = [
        asyncio.async(get_io_from_port(reader,q1)),
        asyncio.async(process_queue(q1, q2)),
        asyncio.async(put_io_to_port(writer, q2)),]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()     # main loop declaration
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I removed the rasks = [....] as I would assume the tasks would not be executed.      From what I see the reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('192.168.1.103', 5555) function is part of the main() loop and it is OK to do so. I definitely misunderstood this.   Thx for the clarity on the queues - there are many examples on web that are actually wrong! I will give this a try now. Appreciated.

Comment: @devOpenID Are you talking about your original example? In your  code, the call to `asyncio.open_connection` is being made outside of the event loop context, in a normal (non-coroutine) function. Putting a `yield` or `yield from` in a normal function/method turns it into a generator, so the body of `main` never runs actually when you call `main()`. That's why you don't see `'Start'` get printed when you run your example code.

Comment: @devOpenID Oh, I also missed that you want each coroutine to be an infinite loop. I've updated the example code to do that. You just need to add a `while True:` loop to each one.

Comment: Oooops I was not clear enough. As you said, in my code. Look like I have more homework on getting to grips here. Thx

Comment: If I understand your text answer correctly, the comment `# do these tasks ...` should be removed from the code.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Good point, thanks. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: No, I mean the statement starting with tasks = [ asyncio.async........ etc up to ] - I need to remove the tasks = [] so that the ayncio.async etc. is exposted otherwise how are these visible/part of the main loop?

Comment: @devOpenID You can if you want to, but it's not necessary. Calling `asyncio.async(coro())` will register `coro` with the event loop. It doesn't matter that you're storing the `Task` returned by the `asyncio.async` call directly into a `tasks` list. So `tasks = [asyncio.async(coro())]` works the same as `asyncio.async(coro())`

Comment: Ok thanks - I have placed the consolidated script below - however it still does not work. It seems the q1 or the process_queue() does not execute for some reason.  The print statement do not fire off so I assume it fails before this. Using a network analyser shows the app not generating any traffic

Comment: @devOpenID Which print statements do not fire off? Have you confirmed that you're successfully receiving data from the remote side - meaning that in `get_io_from_port`, the `data_i = yield from reader.read(1200)` call returns something?

Comment: Via the network analyser I can see data entering from the remote server however I get a debugger message of ........ Task was destroyed but it is pending!      task: <Task pending coro=<get_io_from_port() running at /home/trial.py:383> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>   Also I placed a print(data_i) script after the data_i = yield from reader.read(1200) - this not much help if afraid as it does not fire.

Comment: In the meantime, I have updated Python to 3.4.3 in order to incorporate all the asyncio minor updates.  I can get the data from the imput port onto the q1 in get_io_from_port(reader, q1). However   tmp = yield from q1.get() in process_queue(q1, q2) does not see the increment in the queue

Comment: @dano the app crashed with "Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<put_io_to_port() ...."  As per the latest asyncio  https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html at 18.5.11.8. Chain coroutines correctly - implied is a issue of order, somehow there is an interdependencies between the functions leading to the crash. Including "yield from" to force order, the function get_io_from_port() gets data from the port and puts it on the q1. Everything stops at that point.   Surely info in q1 means process_queue(q1, q2) should fire off?  There is something missing but what?

Comment: @dano Got it!  if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()     # main loop declaration
    loop.run_until_complete(main())    change this to the following:
if __name__ == '__main__':
 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # main loop declaration
 asyncio.async(main())
 loop.run_forever()    and bingo it now works!!  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
import queue
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def process_queue(q1, q2):
    while True:
        tmp = yield from q1.get()
        if tmp == 'ABCDEF':
            yield from q2.put('12345')
        elif tmp == 'GHIJKL':
            yield from q2.put('67890')
        else:
            print('There is a data error')

@asyncio.coroutine
def put_io_to_port(writer, q2):
    while True:
        try:
            data = yield from q2.get()
            writer.write(data)
        except IOError as e:
            print('OUT Port issue: ', e)

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_io_from_port(reader, q1):
    while True:
        try:
            data_i = yield from reader.read(1200)
            yield from q1.put(data_i)
        except IOError as e:
            print('IN Port issue: ', e)

@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    q1 = asyncio.Queue()
    q2 = asyncio.Queue()

    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('192.168.1.103', 5555)
                # high-level call open streams - read and write

    print('Start')

    asyncio.async(get_io_from_port(reader,q1))  # changed items so not
    asyncio.async(process_queue(q1, q2))        # in task list otherwise
    asyncio.async(put_io_to_port(writer, q2))   # they are not visible


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()     # main loop declaration
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Find comments inline with code to understand the problem.

Comment: You should add this as an edit to your initial question, not as a new answer.